# How do I display an XML element, parsing it with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have a fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/j8Y76/

When you click Process log, it should display the contents of the "to"
tag.  (on the console).

```
$('#doProcessLog').click(function(){
    var XMLstring = $.parseXML($.trim($('#log-a').val()));
    var out = $(XMLstring).find('note to').each(function(i, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

However,
It displays the whole element with the tags, but if I try to output it to an alert box or div element as text, it comes back as "Object "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.log($(data).text());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N3WsV/)

If you are expecting only one `to` node then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#doProcessLog').click(function () {
        var XMLstring = $.parseXML($.trim($('#log-a').val()));
        var out = $(XMLstring).find('note to').text();
        console.log('out:', out)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H7aue/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `.textContent` like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#doProcessLog').click(function(){
        var XMLstring = $.parseXML($.trim($('#log-a').val()));
        var out = $(XMLstring).find('note to').each(function(i, data){
            console.log(data.textContent);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

that's because data in your snippet is an object indeed. if you need to append it to some div, try $("#div").append(data)
or, if you need to show the tags in alert box, try alert(data.outerHTML)